# Nested IF statements in Access sql (asp classic)

Tags: sql, if-statement, asp-classic

I would like to find a way to merge the following 4 queries using IF statements in my ADO object (on mdb database)

```
    SELECT * FROM promo WHERE cocategory = 'ri' and codart = '00010089' and costart <= date() and coend >= date() and copre >= 1 order by copre asc
    SELECT * FROM promo WHERE cocategory = 'ri' and codart = '00010089' and costart <= date() and coend >= date() and copr is not null
    SELECT * FROM milis WHERE codelis = '3' and codart = '00010089' and listart < date() and liend > date() and liqta > 0 order by liqta asc
    SELECT * FROM milis WHERE codelis = '3' and codart = '00010089' and listart < date() and liend > date()
```

on EOF (empty) from the first query, get the second, etc... until one of them returns a record.